# Wifi goes down after some time

Tags: wifi, network-interface, manjaro

My wifi goes down and I have to reboot. I never paid attention to this until it started to annoy me. Here are logs:

```
kernel rtl8723be: Init MAC failed
wpa_supplicant wlp3s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

**OS: Manjaro**

**DE / WM: KDE**

**CPU: Intel i3-5005U (4) @ 1.900GHz**

**GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500**

Here are logs:

```
[   86.599277] warning: `kdeconnectd' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   99.907320] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   99.907333] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   99.907337] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1975.808497] perf: interrupt took too long (2605 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 76500
[ 2630.771486] perf: interrupt took too long (3312 > 3256), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 60300
[ 3218.188929] perf: interrupt took too long (4195 > 4140), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 47400
[ 4103.788232] perf: interrupt took too long (5382 > 5243), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 36900
[ 4246.977974] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[ 4246.977991] wlp3s0: Connection to AP 1c:3d:2f:35:1a:78 lost
[ 4257.644636] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[ 4285.929176] rtl8723be: Init MAC failed
```

Could you help me please :)

Comment: so the error is `Failed to initialize driver interface` after some time of it working? Any idea how long it works before it fails

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that. But there is some other err too. ```init MAC failed```.  I provided logs

Comment: OK, I only referred to one error, but I did see both - my question was more about how long the wifi works before it fails, is it always 1Hr 10Min 46Sec

Comment: Not always. Occasionally it fails as soon as after rebooting

Comment: So, there's no pattern

Comment: And, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: research - rtl8723be: Init MAC failed - there's some information out there, not sure which will help

Comment: could you give all information for fixing

Comment: there's multiple search results - not sure which will help - guess you'll have to try